# Selenium IDE - Typing values stored in an array into a textbox?

Tags: arrays, ide, selenium, typing

There's a webpage I'm trying to test that has multiple textboxes.  I've gotten to the point where I can retrieve all the values in every textbox and store them into an array, but I'm stuck on how to type those same values into the textboxes again.

Here's what I have so far in Selenium:

[image: What I have so far]
**Larger view:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb93k.png

The stored variable 'count' is simply the number of rows in the table, and isn't causing a problem.  The part I've circled in red is where the problem comes in.

When I run this test, instead of typing the value stored in the array at that index, it simply types:

[image]

This continues all the way until the end.

The variable 'i' is properly inserted, but for some reason instead of grabbing that value, it simply types it into the textbox.

Does anyone know how I can get the correct value in the array?

Below is the problematic line:

```
type | javascript{this.browserbot.getUserWindow().getTestingHooks('TextBoxValue_' + storedVars['i'])} | ${textBoxArray[${i}]} |
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm using Selenium library through Robot Tests Framework. I'm not using any IDE, just using HTML to make test cases and defining new keywords.

When ever i want to access a list variable item, i just use the following sintaxe

@{list_variable_name}[0]

note that ${variable_name} is to access a single value variable or the reference to the list variable. If we want to access a list item we need to use @ instead of $.

If i understand your situation right, 
@{textBoxArray}[${i}] should work for you.

Try also
${textBoxArray**}**[${i}] because it seems that your are simply misplaycing the last }.

More details at
http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.5.4/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace your circled reference to `${textBoxArray[${i}]` with

```
javascript{storedVars['textBoxArray['+storedVars['j']+']']}
```

Read [this blog post](http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2008/03/selenium-ide-test-tips.html) for more information, especially the section about 'Setting and getting variables'.

Quoting from the article, consider

```
store | 10 | x
```

> This obviously sets x=10. There are a couple of ways to reference it:
>   ${x} or storedVars['x']. They're not the same.

In particular

> You can't assign anything to ${x}.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert one more command before your problematic line:

```
getEval | storedVars['text'] = storedVars['textBoxArray'][storedVars['i']];
```

And change problematic line to:

```
type | javascript{this.browserbot.getUserWindow().getTestingHooks('TextBoxValue_' + storedVars['i'])} | ${text}
```

Also it will be probably helpful to declare your array in the beginning of the test:

```
storeEval | new Array() | textBoxArray
```